# Does cash back apply to online payments with credit card

Tags: credit-card, cash

In this review of [MBNA cash back master card](http://www.milliondollarjourney.com/top-cash-back-credit-cards-in-canada.htm)

they list several points by which you can get cash back every time you use the card.
About this point:

> And, you’ll always earn 1% cash back on all of your other qualifying
>   net retail purchases (up to $1,250/month spending**)

Does this include automated online credit card payments like (charity donation, telephone/internet bill etc. etc etc.) What is a **qualifying net retail purchases**

Comment: did you check the website for the credit card?

Comment: The website has the vague clause 'eligible purchases'     https://www.applyonlinenow.com/CACCapp/Ctl/entry?sc=COMP&lc=en_CA

Comment: Yes. I have a different card, and I see the 2% back regardless of whether it's live or on line. I once asked 2 charities if they preferred a check and both said 'no'. It was cheaper and faster to process the online payments, and I'm good for $200+ in cash back each year just from the donations, instead of cutting checks.

Answer (score 1):

Retail purchases are purchases made at retail, i.e.: as a consumer/individual customer. That would include any "standard" individual expenditure, but may exclude wholesale sales or purchases from merchants who identify themselves as service providers to businesses. Specifics of these limitations really depend on your card issuer, and you should inquire with the customer service at what are their specific eligibility requirements.

As an example, here in the US many cards give high cash-back for gasoline purchases, but only at "retail" locations. That excludes wholesale/club sellers like Costco, for example.